# jQuery load function inside jQuery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to parse a large amount of data from another website trough JavaScript and jQuery and (I'm new to both) so the problem here is the function inside the 2nd jQuery `load()` is not working.

```
function load() {

 var r = 0;
 var cols = [4,5,8,9,10];
 $('#Parser').load('url #tableID', function () {
   var r = $('#Parser').find('label').length;

   for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
     $('#table').append('<tr id="'+i+'"></tr>')

     for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
       $('#'+i).append('<td id="c'+i+j+'"></td>')
       $('#c'+i+j).load('url #tableId\\:Row'+i+'\\:Col'+cols[j], function() {
         $('#c'+i+j).html($('#c'+i+j).children().text());
       });
     }
   }
   $('#Parser').html('');
 });
}
```

So if tested this on its own with static id's and it works

```
$('#test').load('url #tableId\\:Row1\\:Col1', function() {
   $('#test').html($('#test').children().text());
});
```

I need to parse the code by column and row like this because the webpage where I'm getting the data from has the data I want scattered over the columns on the `cols` variable and I find how many rows the table has on the `r` variable

I don't know if it's a logic problem or just a misuse of the functions but I have been struggling the whole day and I needed help.

The main `load()` function is called when the page starts, and this outputs the whole element instead of only the text

```
var time =new Date().getTime();
var rc = 0;
load();
refresh();

function load() {
var r = 0;
var cols = [4,5,8,9,10];

$('#Parser').load('url #tableID', function () {
  var r = $('#Parser').find('label').length;
  if (r != 0) {
    //Simulating going back to this page
    $('body').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white'});
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      if (rc < r) {
        $('#table').append('<tr id="'+i+'"></tr>')
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        if (rc < r) {
          $('#'+i).append('<td id="c'+i+j+'"></td>')
        }
        col =  $('#c'+i+j).load('url #tableId\\:Row'+i+'\\:Col'+cols[j],function() {
          if ($('#c'+i+j).html != col){
            $('#c'+i+j).html('');
          }
        });

      }
    }
  }else {
    if (rc != 0 ) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rc; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length ; j++) {
          $('#c'+i+j).html('');
        }
      }
    }
    if ($('body').css('background-color') != 'white') {
      //Simulating another page
      $('body').css({'background-color':'white','color':'black'});
    }
  }
  $('#Parser').html('');
  if (rc < r) {
    rc = r ;
  }
});
}
function refresh() {
 if(new Date().getTime() - time >= 10000){
  load();
  setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
}else{
  setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
}
}
```

This is my full javascript on the page
the previous code is my atempt on processing it to text on a simpler way

Comment: Who calls the main `load()` function?

Comment: What do you mean by that?, i can guess you are asking what its for , it gets the table so i can count its rows, which is pretty stupid but i only know it this way. The load() function is called when the page opens

Comment: I'm asking because maybe when the `load()` function gets called, the `DOM` might not have been rendered yet, which would explain your `$('el')` not finding any elements at all.

Comment: But I tought that the code inside the $().load(function) on both loads is only executed after it finishes

Comment: I don't know how your `HTML` is being rendered, (you should include your `HTML` as code description), if the same function works outside the main `load()` then it has to be either that, your `HTML` not rendering on time or your `select` is not correct.

Comment: If your javascript/jquery is loaded at the top of the body, it will try to execute when it is read.  If the "#Parser" element hasn't been rendered yet, it won't do anything.  To test this, you could wrap everything you have in a `$(document).ready(function () { /* Your code here */ });` block and then it won't execute the jquery until the document is done loading.

Comment: If i put an alert inside the second $().load(function(){} it doesn't get triggered, so it renders everything except whats inside the second $().load(function(){}

Comment: Try what I put on my answer first, we need to rule out the misuse of a domready load function.

Comment: I've tried wrapping it on $(document).ready(function () {}) and it continues the same

Comment: You don't want to use `load()` to the same url inside your for loop as a way to parse sub-elements.  Your main/first `load()` has what you need already.  Use and parse what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it was a pretty easy fix, inside the second load function I have replaced
the

```
$('#c'+i+j).html($('#c'+i+j).children().text());
```

to

```
$(this).html($(this).text());
```

And it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function load()
{
    ...your code...
}

$(document).ready(load);
```

Maybe the function is not being called on time, make sure you call it AFTER the `DOM` has been rendered.

Comment: Or you could wrap your load() function code inside equivalent .ready() method like so `$(function(){ //main load function code goes here... var l = 0; var cols = [4,5,8,9,10]; ... });`